# Notation with Complex inner product space question

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products, orthogonality

I am trying to show that for a complex inner product space then:

$$
\| x+y \| = \|x-y\| \quad \text{and} \quad \| x+iy \| = \|x-iy\| \implies x\perp y
$$

From this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1727602/151735), I can see that the left hand side of the above implication implies that both Re$\langle x,y\rangle = 0$ and Im$ \langle x,y \rangle =0$ so the result follows from there.

I am confused about the difference between the two conditions though, since $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$, does the first statement $\| x+y \| = \|x-y\|$ imply that $x,y$ are restricted to the reals, and the second the most general case? I don't quite understand why we need both

Comment: Reading the equations that you quoted: The first condition implies that their scalar product, not themselves, is pure imaginary. The second implies that that their scalar product is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implies no restriction whatsoever. It's just that $\|x+y\|=\|x-y\|$ alone, does not imply that $x\perp y$. For instance, in $\mathbb C^2$ let 
$$
x=(0,1),\ \ \ y=(0,i)
$$
Then $$ \|x+y\|=\|(0,1+i)\|=|1+i|=\sqrt2=|1-i|=\|(0,1-i)\|=\|x-y\|,$$
while $\langle x,y\rangle=i\ne0$.

The reason we need both is, as seen above, that one of them is not enough.